# SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED vs SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

In SDL, what is the difference between these two window events?

```
SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED
SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED
```

In the wiki doc page there is [this](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEvent) code sample:

```
    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED:
        SDL_Log("Window %d resized to %dx%d",
                event->window.windowID, event->window.data1,
                event->window.data2);
        break;
    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED:
        SDL_Log("Window %d size changed to %dx%d",
                event->window.windowID, event->window.data1,
                event->window.data2);
        break;
```

But I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [the SDL Wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEventID):

> **SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED**
>
> window has been resized to data1 x data2; this event is always preceded by `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED`
>
> **SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED**
>
> window size has changed, either as a result of an API call or through the system or user changing the window size; this event is followed by `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED` if the size was changed by an external event, i.e. the user or the window manager